# Excel Multiple worksheets to Access tables

Tags: database, excel, ms-access, vba

I have received a database dump from someone in a single Excel file .xlsx that has over 50 worksheets in it. In order for me to make sense of it, I will have to upload it to a database and start pulling some information together.

I am more comfortable with Ms Access so staying with it for now.

How can I import this single file with all 50 worksheets inside into 50 tables separately in Access db?

Can someone please help as I am getting error message when using a simple External data option in Access.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Excel.Application` Object, to get from the Excel `Workbook` all the names in the `Worksheets` Collection, and register all names of sheets in the workbook:

```
Dim App As Object                                            'Excel interface
Dim File As Object                                           'Your file     
Dim ws As Variant                                             'Your worksheet

Set App = CreateObject("Excel.Application")                  'This opens excel application windows
Set File = App.Workbooks.Open(fileName)                      'This opens your particular excel file (or workbook)

For each ws In File
    'Register Name in a table named tblSheetNames, Containing a field named 'ShtNm': 
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblSheetNames(ShtNm) VALUES ('" & ws.Name & "')"
Next
'Close the App to allow link to the Excel file
App.Close: Set App = Nothing
```

Then import all these worksheets:

```
'Import all these worksheets:
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblSheetNames")
Do While Not rst.Eof
    'Link to SpreadSheet, **make sure you add the '!' to the spread-sheet-name for the *Range* parameter**
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Temp", fileName, rst!ShtNm & "!"
    'Dump sheet into table 'MyTable' and then Delete Link:
    CurrenDb.TableDefs.Delete("Temp")
rst.MoveNext: Loop
```

[add the '!' to the spread-sheet-name for the *Range* parameter](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=81948)

Comment: Sorry for my limited knowledge and a silly question. Where am I inserting these macros in the same excel file or Access db?

Comment: In Access. You will also have to supply a value for `fileName` in the code.

Comment: For second macro I am getting error "An expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of the arguments. I am using ..  Sub ImportData()

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblSheetNames")

Do While Not rst.EOF
    
    'Link to SpreadSheet, **make sure you add the '!' to the spread-sheet-name for the *Range* parameter**
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "Temp", "C:\File.xlsx", rst!ShtNm & "!"
    'Dump sheet into table 'MyTable' and then Delete Link:
    CurrenDb.TableDefs.Delete ("Temp")
rst.MoveNext: Loop

End Sub

Comment: On what line do you get the error? what version of Access are you using? what version is the Excel? Have you created tables `tblSheetNames` and` MyTable`?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

'Import Data from All EXCEL Files in a single Folder via TransferSpreadsheet (VBA)'

```
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim strTable As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
' contains the EXCEL files
strPath = "C:\Documents\"

' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
' the data are to be imported
strTable = "tablename"

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames

' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
' EXCEL file after it's been imported
'       Kill strPathFile

      strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

The idea comes straight form here.

http://www.accessmvp.com/KDSnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpFolderFiles

Check out the link.  You will find several other really cool and utilitarian concepts there.

Comment: Fine code and link you brought  @ryguy7272, please note the request was code for import Worksheets from one file.